# Include documents in each aggregation with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Have a requirement to prepare search result (from server) in a way for UI to display something like shown on [this](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html) page. basically a database equivalent is `group by` queries including [average aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html) for one or more of the sub-groupings.

Apparently it's clear that Elastic Search doesn't have support for returning documents with aggregation feature which was confirmed by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23269138) and [this](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Can-aggregation-return-the-documents-in-each-bucket-td4052175.html) post.

while comparing elastic search with Solr one of the reasons to go with Elastic Search was it's [advanced aggregation features](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html), including nested aggregations and variety of other rich aggregations (including min,max,avg,sum,percentile etc). Given the requirement on hand what's the best server side workaround for achieve results(documents) in each aggregation?

Answer (score 4):

Check the latest release, it contains the top hits aggregation. This might be what you are looking for

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

Comment: :-  since I want all the documents for each bucket should `size` attribute not be put in there when using top-hits-aggregation?