# Retrieve all docs using top_hits aggregation ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using `top_hits` aggregation to retrieve documents along with counts.I need to retrieve all the document based on my earlier post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24920545/include-documents-in-each-aggregation-with-elasticsearch), for which thought passing `size` 0 will do it but it throws following error.

```
org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhaseExecutionException: [my-demo][3]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[0],size[10]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]
at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:162)
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:261)
at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$5.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:206)
at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$5.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:203)
at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23.run(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:517)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: numHits must be > 0; please use TotalHitCountCollector if you just need the total hit count
at org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector.create(TopScoreDocCollector.java:254)
at org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector.create(TopScoreDocCollector.java:238)
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.metrics.tophits.TopHitsAggregator.collect(TopHitsAggregator.java:108)
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.BucketsAggregator.collectBucketNoCounts(BucketsAggregator.java:74)
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.BucketsAggregator.collectExistingBucket(BucketsAggregator.java:63)
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.BucketsAggregator.collectBucket(BucketsAggregator.java:55)
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.terms.GlobalOrdinalsStringTermsAggregator$WithHash.collect(GlobalOrdinalsStringTermsAggregator.java:236)
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregatorFactories$1.collect(AggregatorFactories.java:114)
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.BucketCollector$2.collect(BucketCollector.java:81)
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.BucketsAggregator.collectBucketNoCounts(BucketsAggregator.java:74)
```

Comment: According to elasticseach, size - The maximum number of top matching hits to return per bucket. By default the top three matching hits are returned. so, size = 0 means no documents (i think) so try sending maximum values.

Answer (score 1):

According to elasticseach, size - The maximum number of top matching hits to return per bucket. By default the top three matching hits are returned. so, size = 0 means no documents (i think) so try sending maximum values. –  progrrammer 31 mins ago

Top hit aggregation response is of format,

```
 "top_tags_hits": {
              "hits": {
                 "total": 25365,
                 "max_score": 1,
                 "hits": [
                    {
                       "_index": "stack",
                       "_type": "question",
                       "_id": "602679",
                       "_score": 1,
                       "_source": {
                          "title": "Windows port opening"
                       },
                       "sort": [
                          1370143231177
                       ]
                    }
                 ]
              }
```

here hits - > total give total no of hits, you can use pagination(from, and size) as in search api, to get documents or use maximum integer value [(2^31)-1] to get all the documents.

Hope this helps.

Comment: size=0 will return an error, it's reasonable to try to use size=0 since in other places in ES queries it mean all records. For buckets sizes 100 is max value, not max int