# Elasticsearch regroup and sort data by aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, composite

I’m struggling into doing some aggregations with ElasticSearch.
Here my mapping example:

```
PUT example
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "domain": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
      },
      "rank": {
            "type": "long"
      },
      "ts": {
            "type": "date"
      }
       }
  }
}
```

Each document represents the position of a website domain for a keyword at a specific date.
So for example, if I have 2 websites, apple.com & microsoft.com, with 2 different positions for the keyword “computer”, I will have 2 documents for each domain, with the keyword “computer”.
If i retrieve the documents without aggregations, I will have:

```
"_source" : {
      "keyword" : "computer",
      "domain" : "apple.com",
      "ts" : "2019-04-30",
      "rank" : 12
}

"_source" : {
      "keyword" : "computer",
      "domain" : "microsoft.com",
      "ts" : "2019-04-30",
      "rank" : 9
}
```

I would like to generate a table with some aggregation, in which each row represents a keyword, with the rank of both domains.

```
+----------+---------------+-----------+
|          | microsoft.com | apple.com |
+----------+---------------+-----------+
| computer |             9 |        12 |
+----------+---------------+-----------+
```

I need that the aggregation can be paginated and sorted (by keyword, Microsoft’s rank or Apple’s rank ..)

Do you have any idea how I can achieve that ?
I did the aggregation bellow, but I don’t know how to sort it.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "terms_keyword": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "keyword": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "domain_terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "domain"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "doc": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the result:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "terms_keyword" : {
      "after_key" : {
        "keyword" : "computer"
      },
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : {
            "keyword" : "computer"
          },
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "domain_terms" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "apple.com",
                "doc_count" : 1,
                "doc" : {
                  "hits" : {
                    "total" : {
                      "value" : 12,
                      "relation" : "eq"
                    },
                    "max_score" : 1.0,
                    "hits" : [
                      {
                        "_index" : "example",
                        "_type" : "_doc",
                        "_id" : "1g1jWmoB9OyOTfm4a8kE",
                        "_score" : 1.0,
                        "_source" : {
                          "keyword" : "computer",
                          "domain" : "apple.com",
                          "ts" : "2019-04-30",
                          "rank" : 12
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "key" : "microsoft.com",
                "doc_count" : 1,
                "doc" : {
                  "hits" : {
                    "total" : {
                      "value" : 1,
                      "relation" : "eq"
                    },
                    "max_score" : 1.0,
                    "hits" : [
                      {
                        "_index" : "example",
                        "_type" : "_doc",
                        "_id" : "2Q1jWmoB9OyOTfm4tMl3",
                        "_score" : 1.0,
                        "_source" : {
                          "keyword" : "computer",
                          "domain" : "microsoft.com",
                          "ts" : "2019-04-30",
                          "rank" : 9
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I'm probably not using the correct method, I am open to any suggestions.

Thanks

EDIT:

Ok so I managed to progress thanks to this post [How to group results in elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087288/how-to-group-results-in-elasticsearch)

I used [Field collapse feature in top hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#_field_collapse_example) and now i can regroup by keyword and sort by the 2 domains ranks with sub aggregations:

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "top": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "keyword",
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_tags_hits": {
          "top_hits": {}
        },
        "min_rank_apple": {
          "min": {
            "script": {
              "source": "if (doc.domain.value == \"apple.com\") { doc.rank.value } else { 101 }"
            }
          }
        },
        "min_rank_microsoft": {
          "min": {
            "script": {
              "source": "if (doc.domain.value == \"microsoft.com\") { doc.rank.value } else { 101 }"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can change the **order** in terms aggregation by **keyword**, **min_rank_apple** or **min_rank_microsoft**. But I still can't paginate due to terms aggs. There is the [composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) but I don't think we can order with sub aggregations.